# Resta entre dos campos de diferentes tablas da resultado con exponente y erróneo- SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Tengo dos tablas, en una de ellas está el ID de cada factura y su TOTAL y en otra tabla todos sus pagos.

Lo que necesito es restar la suma de pagos al total de la factura, el problema es que en algunos casos pese a que el total y la suma de los pagos es igual (Por lo que debiera ser cero) me da una diferencia de 1 elevado a x potencia y eso me está dando problemas al sacar sumatorias de saldos.  Les muestro un ejemplo de mi código, donde solo considero una factura; ya intenté cuidando el tipo de dato, con dos select (uno para total y otro para pagos y restar al final) y nada logra funcionarme. Alguna sugerencia al respecto?

```
SELECT 
d.CIDCLIENTE, d.CODIGOCLIENTE,d.TOTAL,SUM(p.PAGADO) AS PAGADO, 
ISNULL(MAX(d.TOTAL)-(SUM(p.PAGADO)),MAX(d.TOTAL)) AS CPENDIENTEMN 
FROM AntSaldo d 
LEFT JOIN PagosAntSal p ON p.FACTPAGADA=d.CIDDOCUMENTO 
WHERE d.CIDCLIENTE=50 AND p.FACTPAGADA=20142 
GROUP BY d.CIDCLIENTE, d.CODIGOCLIENTE, d.TOTAL
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dejame adivinar, estás usando float para tus columnas. Float es un tipo de dato aproximado y puede generar esos resultados. Muestra que la diferencia es de 0.00000000016415321826935, lo cual es muy pequeño y se puede redondear.

Lo mejor sería que conviertas el tipo de dato de tus columnas a decimal, pero si no es posible, puedes simplemente convertir el resultado a decimal o redondear el valor.

```
SELECT  d.CIDCLIENTE, 
        d.CODIGOCLIENTE,
        d.TOTAL,
        SUM(p.PAGADO) AS PAGADO, 
        CONVERT( decimal(12,2), ISNULL(MAX(d.TOTAL)-(SUM(p.PAGADO)),MAX(d.TOTAL))) AS CPENDIENTEMN_CON_CONVERT , 
        ROUND( ISNULL(MAX(d.TOTAL)-(SUM(p.PAGADO)),MAX(d.TOTAL)), 2) AS CPENDIENTEMN_CON_ROUND
FROM AntSaldo d 
LEFT JOIN PagosAntSal p ON p.FACTPAGADA = d.CIDDOCUMENTO 
WHERE   d.CIDCLIENTE = 50 
AND     p.FACTPAGADA = 20142 
GROUP BY d.CIDCLIENTE, 
         d.CODIGOCLIENTE, 
         d.TOTAL;
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu comentario, probé cambiando el tipo de dato y dejaron de mostrarse esas cantidades. Gracias de nuevo.